# Can a small flying vehicle enter Sigil through a portal?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, vehicles, planescape, portals

Say a party of adventures were in a flying vehicle about the size of a large rowboat and went through a portal to Sigil. Would the ship be allowed in?

Comment: I feel like some context would improve your question a bit. What research have you done? Are there any reasons you think it might or might not work?

Comment: I have read or seen nothing about flying vehicles in the sky's of sigil At least in my memory of playing since 2e. As for research? I looked here... Context? A flying ship flys through a portal leading to Sigil. Might or might not work? That is what I am asking....

Comment: I think by research the question is 'what do you already know about who or what is allowed in sigil' or have you just heard about it and are asking without reading any of the setting material etc? Have you seen anything that suggests there are any entry requirements?

Comment: "Would the ship be allowed in?" presupposes that there is someone or something granting or denying access - could you provide information about this entity and why you think they might forbid it?

Comment: While I don't think this question is great, I don't think it meets any criteria for closure.

Comment: @Kirt this being is Lady of Pain and she decided no deity or demon lord can enter the city, and her wishes made it reality. Some suggested that the Sigil, and Lady within it, are but a dream of the real Lady. Her rules are strict, but she's mostly concerned with safety and neutrality of the city, and working infrastructure. Portals and keys concerns her. Theft or murder does not. Why would she forbid a flying boat I don't know as I'm not the one who asked, but it certainly is within her power to do so.

Answer (score 3):

### Currently, only your DM can tell you, but there is nothing that speaks against it

This answer is for [dnd-5e](/questions/tagged/dnd-5e) only.

There is precious little material written about Sigil's portals in any of the official D&D 5e books published so far. The PHB tells you that

> This bustling planar metropolis holds countless portals to other planes and worlds. Sigil is a trader’s city. Goods, merchandise, and information come to it from across the planes. There is a brisk trade in information about the planes, in particular in the command words or items required for the operation of particular portals. These portal keys are highly sought after, and many travelers within the city are looking for a particular portal or a portal key to allow them to continue on their way.

And that's about it. The DMG adds that:

> Portal keys of all kinds are bought and sold here.

With nothing else to go on, this is all up to your DM.  There is no specific reason why a magical flying vehicle would not be able to pass into the city, if it is small enough to fit through whatever portal it is using. Portals come in *many* shapes and sizes. Find one that is large enough, and you are good.

Maybe the upcoming Spelljammer product will add more insight. Until then, how these portals work is entirely up to rulings.

From older editions, where there is more lore about Sigil, we know that gods or demon lords cannot enter the city, and that you cannot directly *plane shift* or *teleport* into it; it can only be entered or left *via* portal. But there is no ban on magic items entering the city. Considering this is a trader's paradise, including for exotic and magic items, it stands to reason that these magic items likewise must enter or leave the city *via* one or more of these gates.